# Why chrome shows video in android device, but opera does not?

Tags: browser, video

Opera has built-in proxy and presser of traffic - it is very useful for me. But opera, instead of to show a video, downloads it. It isn't I want.
How can I (without root and with android 4.3) learn opera to show a video as well as chrome does?

Comment: Maybe the video you're trying to view requires a HTML5 player? I've heard Opera doesn't support those.

Comment: No, it is flash. Android from 4.1 do not support flash player officially, I hear. But somehow chrome ignore it. The second fact is Opera is exactly the same chrome, because it use a chromium. I think there is a solution must be somewhere(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable the `Off-road mode` in Opera then it plays the video rather than downloading it.

Comment: My opera is non-English, what do you mean "off-road mode"? "Pressing mode" needs me as proxy to get a site, where I want to see a video. Nothing passerby to "off-road" in options I did not find.

Comment: Thank you. I handle it. So "off-road mode" translated as "pressing mode". First it must be turned on to surf a site, next it must be turned off and open video in private tab.